# SASS global variables not being passed to partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sass, assets

Basically I have a structure that used to work perfectly in 3.0.x and now it breaks with `undefined variable` errors.

- partials

  - _base.css.sass
  - _header.css.sass
- main.css.sass
- application.css.sass

the `application.css.sass`:

```
//=require 'main'
```

the `main.css.sass`:

```
@import 'partials/base'
@import 'partials/header'
```

Pretty simple stuff.

I get an error on `_header.css.sass`
because it uses a variable defined on `_base.css.sass`

I didn't have this error before, and it makes no sense to me, since we're importing those variables on the `_base.css.sass` in the same context we are importing the `_header.css.sass`.

Am I going to have to import the `_base.css.sass` on every partial too? 
What is the point of the `main.css.sass` requiring global variables if they cannot be used in the own partials you are requiring?

If my structure is completely wrong, please give me an alternative, I'd love suggestions.

Comment: "config.assets.precompile" is your friend :-)

[Just have a look here which really helped me!!!][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134034/using-rails-3-1-assets-pipeline-to-conditionally-use-certain-css

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can't use `//=require` to include "dynamic" SASS stuff like mixins and variables, because that's used just for including the most "static" stuff (like pure CSS). You have to `@import` all your files in `application.css.sass`. Railscasts provides good explanation of this in [episode #268](http://railscasts.com/episodes/268-sass-basics).

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple solution for the original topic. Your application and main css files should be scss files. That means you can use the known syntax:

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require main
 */
```

In main.scss you can import the partials like this:

```
@import 'partials/base'
@import 'partials/header'
```

These files are sass files and you can benefit from the greatness of SASS ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think I had the same problem and what helped was declaring the variables before @imports. Hope this helps someone =).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you HAVE to use the `application.css.sass` as a manifest, or nothing will work.

Basically you can separate everything but they need to be called from the application file because the scopes are not shared.

Little bit too enforcing if you ask me...

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean with "you have to use the … as a manifest"? I'm using `application.css.sass` as my main file where I `@import` all my other files, but I still run into the same problem as described above.

Comment: You are using a .sass where the filename is .scss

Comment: Thanks, it was a typo @raulriera

Comment: Well, it worked for me several times now. In order for the declared variables and mixins to work on the same file, you have to import them with sass, not with sprockets. @Marc

Comment: I'm using sass import-statements but the variables are not available in other files while pre-compiling (using Heroku). I temporarily 'fixed' the problem by importing the sass file with the variables in each and every other sass file, but this is far from an ideal solution.

Comment: @Marc I must think this is a heroku problem. Does it work on your development environment? Never had any problems after I completely switched to sass imports.

Answer (score 0):

It's a sass file. Use `@import` in `application.css.sass` instead of `require`. `require` is for plain css or template engines that don't have an import system.