# sass - extra import statement needed for compass mixin in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, compass-sass

I am using rails 3.1 rc6 and I have 2 files:

1. screen.css.sass
2. partials/_layout.css.sass

Screen 1, looks like this:

```
@import 'compass'
@include global-reset
@include reset-html5

@import "partials/utilities"
@import "partials/layout"
```

In _layout.css.sass which is a partial that I am importing from screen.css.sass, I want to use the pie-clearfix mixin which lives in:

> compass/utilities/general/clearfix

I would have thought that I would not have to add an additional @import directive to the partial because I am importing the whole compass library in screen.css.sass.

But when I try to use it like this:

```
.group
  @include pie-clearfix
```

I get the following error message:

> Undefined mixin 'pie-clearfix'

The only way to get the _layout.css.sass file to render from the asset pipeline is to add the import to the _layout.css.sass:

```
@import "compass/utilities/general/clearfix"
```

It does not seem to be picking up the @import 'compass' from screen.css.sass.

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Comment: I found the answer in this stackoverflow [question][1].

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6269420/11755

Comment: Can you post your answer and accept?