# Zurb Foundation Settings as a Rails Asset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, zurb-foundation, asset-pipeline, sprockets

Zurb Foundation has a nice feature for letting people configure the entire library, by changing some of the Sass variables, found in the `foundation-rails` gem. However, I've been using
[rails-assets](https://rails-assets.org/)
and sprockets to load Foundation as a dependency into my styles, but I would still like to configure the Sass varialbes globally. Is there any cut-and-dry way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sprockets do something different. They compile each stylesheet individually and only stylesheets that have changed get recompiled. See: http://twin.github.io/speedy-sass-with-import-and-sprockets/

So you should import all your partials into `application.css.scss` too. Depending on foundation variables are defined with `!default` you are able to override the variables by putting their definition before the import of the partials.

See also: [SASS global variables not being passed to partials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269420/sass-global-variables-not-being-passed-to-partials)